# How can I validate optional HTML closing tags and missing /'s?

Tags: html, validation, xhtml

Are there any freely available tools that would check for things like a missing `</p>` or `<br>` (instead of `<br />`)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

There is the [w3c validator](http://validator.w3.org/).

You could also use any of the many validating XML parsers to validate your XHTML against one of the [XHTML DTDs](http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/dtds.html) (depending on which one you are using).

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are actually asking:

> How can I convert HTML to XHTML?

In which case, I suggest looking at [HTML Tidy](http://tidy.sf.net) or a combination of [HTML::HTML5::Parser](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?HTML::HTML5::Parser) and a bit of code to output the resulting DOM as an XML document.

Comment: Yes, I now realize that I've lived on a desert island for almost ten years... thinking that HTML4 (and the upcoming HTML5) were supposed to be sticklers on those aspects of xHTML. I now see that <br> is expected, not <br />, while </p> and others are optional.

Anyway, what option in tidy enforces xHTML? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The [W3C Markup Validation Service](http://validator.w3.org/) lets you check the validity of the most commonly used web documents like html, xhtml... 
You can validate your code by providing a URI, File Upload or by pasting.

The Validation Service is open source so if you need a offline version you can also download the code and use it locally. [(link to source code)](http://validator.w3.org/source/)